# Convert string to array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, string, google-visualization, url-encoding

I have urlencoded JSON data:

```
%5B%5B"Task"%2C"Hours%20per%20Day"%5D%2C%5B"Work"%2C11%5D%2C%5B"Eat"%2C2%5D%2C%5B"Commute"%2C2%5D%2C%5B"Watch%20TV"%2C2%5D%2C%5B"Sleep"%2C7%5D%5D
```

I have already decoded it to:

```
"[["Task","Hours per Day"],["Work",11],["Eat",2],["Commute",2],["Watch TV",0.5],["Sleep",7]]"
```

As you can see, this is a string, not an array, and I am trying to convert it to an array.

Sidenote:

I am making a page which will display charts using Google Charts that is having this problem. All help is welcome!

Comment: `eval` is your friend

Comment: or JSON.parse -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9bzVg/

Comment: It's fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: @adeneo `eval` is actually your enemy, use it wisely or never at all. This case is not a wise case to use it since the input is likely from a URL, which could be spoofed for phishing and you'd be subject to script injection.

Comment: @JuanMendes - "eval is your friend" is more of a joke really, as opposed to the usual "eval is evil".

Comment: @adeneo Doesn't saying "eval is your friend" encourage its use unless the OP already knows the problems with it? If they do know the problems with `eval`, they already know the answer to this question, no?

Comment: I know the problems with eval

Comment: @Vulpus And you didn't know that eval can execute code for a literal array and return it?

Comment: I wasn't thinking. I knew that eval could be dangerous. But this page will only be requested by my pages as "I am making a page which will display charts using google charts that is having this problem" implies that this page will only be requested by me.

Comment: @Vulpus That doesn't mean someone couldn't send a phishing link with a spoofed URL parameter containing a script.

Comment: Yes. I have already switched to JSON.parse but I am happy that I have found a answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var jsArray = JSON.parse('[["Task","Hours per Day"],["Work",11],["Eat",2],["Commute",2],["Watch TV",0.5],["Sleep",7]]');
console.log(jsArray[0][0]) // "Task"
console.log(jsArray[0][1]) // "Hours per Day"
```

Using `eval` would also work but would expose you to script injection if you are getting that value from an untrusted source, like the URL parameters, which can be spoofed for fishing

Comment: Good. Thank you for submitting an answer instead of a comment. That way I can accept it